# Python - syntax error with ADS101X ADC library

Tags: python, bbc-microbit

I'm using (new to me) [Microbit python V2](https://python.microbit.org/v/2) with [Adafruit_ADS1X15](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ADS1X15) library.
After flashing to the microbit the serial output shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__", line 4
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
MicroPython v1.9.2-34-gd64154c73 on 2017-09-01; micro:bit v1.0.1 with nRF51822
Type "help()" for more information.
```

Does this mean the library is not compatible with this version of Python; if so where to go next please?

Comment: Please post the code you executed, you may have just made a syntax error in your own Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Oops - now I have relooked at the code I realise that it's cpp, not Python!